# Is it possible to put a padding/border around an image?

Tags: html, css

I needed a black padding around my image but I don't know how to do it.
If anyone knows please comment how to do so.
Thank You for your time, I appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry Raj, you are asking some very basic questions. You should have a better understanding of the basics, such as the `src` attribute in an `img` tag is where the path\url to the image goes. I suggest you do a few more basic tutorials to improve your understanding. StackOverflow is not really a place to learn the basic fundamentals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in either way:

```
<img src="/path/to/img" id="highlight">
```

css:

```
#highlight {
    padding: 5px;
    backgroung: black;
    /* or */
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: But where do I put the Image URL?
Or the image link address?

Comment: In the html the img tag has an attribute src there you put as the value the link to your image. In my example the link would be `/path/to/img`

Comment: I'm new so i really need help>

Comment: Sorry. Will you say it in another way Please?

Answer (score 1):

In **HTML file add**

```
<img src="your-image-url"/>
<style>
.img{    //image class
  border:solid #000 5px; // bordertype color Width 
}
</style>
```

or you colud add style inline as

```
<img src="your-image-url" style="border:solid #000 2px;" />
```

please provide the code for exact answer.

Comment: But where do I put the Image URL?

Comment: Or the image link address?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: DO you have the basic knowledge of HTML and CSS ??